# It keeps on getting 'Cannot find symbol' error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i really dont know how to fix this. help me

Down here is the code that im doing. I very much know that my code is correct but when i try to compile it. it keeps getting on 'Cannot find symbol error'

[Cannot find Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHxGV.jpg)

```
systemfinal.java:10 error: cannot find symbol
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

systemfinal.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class systemfinal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String order, again;
        int quantity, total, loop1, quantity1, quantity2 = 0;
        int price1, price2;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t\t   Welcome to Karenderya ni Ineng!\t\t");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tMENU\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("   Order code\t\t Meal\t\t\t\t Price ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("      Meals: ");
        System.out.println("      (A1)   \t\t Sisig\t\t\t\t P50");
        System.out.println("      (A2)   \t\t Sisig at Lechon\t\t P60");
        System.out.println("      (A3)   \t\t Lechon\t\t\t\t P50");
        System.out.println("      (A4)   \t\t Pancit Canton\t\t\t P35");
        System.out.println("      (A5)   \t\t Adobong manok\t\t\t P40");
        System.out.println("      (A6)   \t\t Inihaw na Bangus\t\t P60");
        System.out.println("      (A7)   \t\t Sinigang na Bangus\t\t P60");
        System.out.println("      (A8)   \t\t Inihaw na Pusit\t\t P60");
        System.out.println("      (A9)   \t\t Chicken Inasal\t\t\t P60");
        System.out.println("      (A10)   \t\t Fried Chicken\t\t\t P50");
        System.out.println("      Rice: ");
        System.out.println("      (B1)   \t\t Plain Rice \t\t\t P10");
        System.out.println("      (B2)   \t\t Java Rice\t\t\t P10");
        System.out.println("      (B3)   \t\t Fried Rice\t\t\t P10");
        System.out.println("      Drinks: ");
        System.out.println("      (C1)   \t\t Iced tea\t\t\t P15");
        System.out.println("      (C2)   \t\t Softdrinks\t\t\t P25");
        System.out.println("      (C3)   \t\t Water\t\t\t\t P10");
        System.out.println("      (C4)   \t\t Juice\t\t\t\t P20");
        System.out.println("      Desserts: ");
        System.out.println("      (D1)   \t\t Halo-Halo\t\t\t P40");
        System.out.println("      (D2)   \t\t Buko Pie (per box)\t\t P150");
        System.out.println("      (D2)   \t\t Pitchi pitchi (per box)\t P100");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        do {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Enter Code Order: ");
            order = br.readLine();
            if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A1")) {
                price1 = 50;
                System.out.println("Order Description: Sisig ");
            }
            else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("A2")) {
                price1 = 60;
                System.out.println("Order Description: Sisig at Lechon ");
            }

            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            total += price1 * quantity1;

            System.out.print("Another Order?  (Y/N) : ");
            again = br.readLine();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                loop1 = loop1 + 1;
            }
            else {
                loop1 = loop1 - 100;
            }
        } while (loop1 == 1);

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Total Price: " + price2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, almost everything in the 76 lines of code you've posted is irrelevant to the actual problem you're facing. Please reduce this to a [mcve], indent the code more readably, and edit it into the question. Include the error messages as *text* rather than as a screenshot - and explain how you think the compiler *should* be able to find the `BufferedReader` class. (Hint: what package is it in, and which packages have you imported?)

Comment: Proper indentation will help immensely.

Comment: If one answer fix your problem. I think at least a couple of the answer do please mark your question as answered. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add below import statements.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

and initialize the variables `total, loop1, price1 and price2` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to import the classes you're using within your code. `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` are not contained in `java.util` but in `java.io`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

or for a grouped import

```
import java.io.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

The BufferReader class is in java.io.BufferedReader
So you need to import it at the beginning of your program

put this under

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
```